Getting selection of items from user using tkinter, and want to use user selection as a variable in the code
I am giving a list of items for user to select, and when user makes selection, I intend to use that selection later in the code. But somehow, the code keeps on running and nothing happens. So not sure if user selection is not been included in the variable.
gens = ER3['Bus Name'].drop_duplicates()
    def select_gens():
        global selected_value
        selected_value = [lb.get(i) for i in lb.curselection()]
        root.destroy()
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Select gens")
    items = gens
    lb = tk.Listbox(root, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE)
    for item in items:
        lb.insert(tk.END, item)
    lb.pack(pady=20)
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Select", command=select_gens)
    button.pack()
    root.mainloop()

    result.columns = result.columns.str.strip()
    filter = result['Bus Name'].str.contains('|'.join(selected_value))
    result_filter = result.loc[filter]

Is there any better way to get the user selection and save it as a variable? Essentially, I want to use user's selection as a filter in excel column.

Are you saying that root.mainloop() never returns?  Because your code works perfectly for me.  Are you running this in an IDE?  Which operating system?

@TimRoberts Yep, the code never returns anything for me, it just keeps on running, and I am running it in Pycharm on windows 10.

@TimRoberts Essentially the end goal is to get the input selection from user, and want to filter a dataframe for the input selection. So somehow use input selection to pass as strings to filter column in a dataframe.

It is problematic to run GUI apps inside a GUI IDE.  What happens if you run the script from a command line?
